# Autolayout to make a viewController's view to fill screen when rotating?

Tags: ios, autolayout

I have added this to my viewDidLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
     [super viewDidLoad];


     [self.view setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
     NSDictionary *views = @{ @"view" : self.view };
     [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint
                                constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|[view]|"
                                options:kNilOptions
                                metrics:nil
                                views:views]]; 
}
```

I does not work. I have a view controller and I want to make it so when I rotate the deice the view adapts to the new orientation. So if I go from portrait to landscape I want the view to get wider enough and decrease its height... so normal behavior I used to be able to do real quick before auto layout.

How can I achieve this? What am I doing wrong?

Thank

Comment: You shouldn't need to do this even when you're using auto layout. What result do you see if you comment out this code?

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse constraint format: 
Unable to interpret '|' character, because the related view doesn't have a superview 
|[view]| 
       ^'

Comment: You get that error when you comment out the code, or when you have the code (you should comment out the whole viewDidLoad method)?

Comment: Ok, so I thought I needed to do that because after rotation the view controller's view always have the same frame: didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation. frame = {{0, 0}, {320, 568}}. So, is that how it's supposed to be then?

Comment: I get that error when I have that code in. If I comment out the code in viewDidLoad I get NO error

Comment: Yes, the frame doesn't change. If you log the bounds, you should see that change (in viewDidAppear anyway, I don't remember whether it logs correctly in viewDidLoad).

Comment: The view controller's view's frame shouldn't be the same in landscape and portrait unless rotation is disabled...

Comment: @nhgrif, yeah, you're right, both should log correctly if you do the log at the correct time (like in viewWillLayoutSubviews).

Comment: @nhgrif, the frame is always frame = {{0, 0}, {320, 568}}, but the bounds do change accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A view controller's view (what you're messing with here) automatically fills the entire screen no matter the orientation.  You do not (and should not) be setting auto-layout constraints on this view.  Instead, you need to set up your auto-layout constraints on the subviews.

Comment: so, can you tell me why then the frame always stays portrait? When didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation is called and the phone now is in landscape the self.view of the view controller is still:  frame = {{0, 0}, {320, 568}}. Why?

Comment: ok, so I found an answer here that states that the bounds do change, which is the case for me too. thanks. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7861342/the-frame-size-of-the-view-is-not-changing-on-rotation-when-the-view-is-created